# Dependencies between School, Student and Lesson models

Tags: laravel, oop, model-view-controller, model, controller

I have a School model that has many Student models who attend to multiple Lesson models, I also have a controller for each one.

I need the ability to access the school type (large, small, etc...), whether I am in the Student, Lesson or School controller.

Would this approach be correct in a strict OOP world?

```php
// School model
class School
{
    ...

    public getSchoolType()
    {
        return $this->schoolType;
    {

}

// Student model
class Student
{
    ...

    public school()
    {
        return $this->school;
    {

}

// Lesson model
class Lesson
{
    ...

    public student()
    {
        return $this->student;
    {

}

// Student controller 
class StudentController
{
    public function show(Student $student)
    {
        $schoolType = $student->school->schoolType;
        return view('students', array($schoolType));
    }
}

// Lesson controller 
class LessonController
{
    public function show(Lesson $lesson)
    {
        $schoolType = $lesson->student->school->schoolType;
        return view('lessons', array($schoolType));
    }
}
```

If lessons relate to students in a Many-to-Many way, how do I get the schoolType within the Lesson controller if there is no students attending that Lesson?

My point is, should I actually get the schoolType through the Student model like `$lesson->school->schoolType` or it should be more like `$lesson->student->school->schoolType`, so lessons simply don't relate directly to students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use eloquent relationship [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

In your School Model-

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
}
```

In you Student model-

```
public function lessons()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
}
public function school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(School::class);
}
```

In your Lesson Model-

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
public function school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(School::class);
}
```

now you can easily access `schoolType` as you can traverse to model to model using this `relationship`. An example would be, In your `Lesson Controller`-

```
$lession = Lession::find($lession_id);
$schoolType = $lession->student->school->schoolType;
```

If you want to access `schoolType` directly from Lesson-

```
$lession = Lession::find($lession_id);
$schoolType = $lession->school->schoolType;
```

Comment: So then, how do I access schoolType from the lesson model if the lesson I am handeling has not yet been assigned to any student?

Comment: you can't as there is no relation between lesson and school, you can only if there is a student involved, that's what you have specified in your question, right??

Comment: But from the lesson controller I need to know what school I am.

Comment: then you need to make a additional belongsTo relationship in Lesson model like belongsTo student.